# How does CBlockLocator class works?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

The [CBlockLocator](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/6b24dfe24d2ed50ea0b06ce1919db3dc0e871a03/src/primitives/block.h#L120) strucuture's purpose is:

> Describes a place in the block chain to another node such that if the
> other node doesn't have the same branch, it can find a recent common
> trunk. The further back it is, the further before the fork it may be.

```
/** Describes a place in the block chain to another node such that if the
 * other node doesn't have the same branch, it can find a recent common trunk.
 * The further back it is, the further before the fork it may be.
 */
struct CBlockLocator
{
    std::vector<uint256> vHave;
```

But it's not clear to me how does it works. How does the sender specify the Block with `A` in this structure? Does the `vHave` contains a list of contiguous block hashes previous to `A` and `A` itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the `vHave` contains a list of contiguous block hashes previous to `A` and `A` itself?

Pretty much.

`CBlockLocators` are just a list of block hashes, with most recent blocks first. Of course, it would be expensive to send all of the block hashes that precede `A`, so the list contains hashes farther and farther apart as the blocks get older.

It starts with `A` and the 9 blocks that came before it. The vast majority of reorgs will be within these 10 blocks, so it just lists all 10 and there's a pretty high likelihood that the forking point will be in there. But after that, hashes start being spaced out exponentially. It starts with 2 blocks before the last in the list, then 4, then 8, and so on, until the genesis block is reached.

The list ends up having `ceil(log2(n)) + 11` hashes. Currently that's 31 block hashes.

Comment: Excellent approach Andrew.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just a question, the `n` in the  `ceil(log2(n)) + 11` is the height of the block `A`?

Comment: Yes. `n` is the number of blocks in the chain.